# Searching a custom list view in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, filtering

I am using a custom list view and I get unexpected results on search.I would ideally like to search on particular columns in the list for example I would like to search on a Invoice number or a contact number or by name of the person.
The following is my code.

```
   public void showJson(String json) {
        final Context billsctx = getActivity();
        ParseBills pb = new ParseBills(json);
        pb.parseJSON();

        bl = new BillsCustomList((Activity) billsctx, ParseBills.doc_no, ParseBills.date, ParseBills.cust_name, ParseBills.cust_number, ParseBills.item_count, ParseBills.total_wt,
                ParseBills.total,ParseBills.balance, ParseBills.bill_type);


        all_listView.setAdapter(bl);




        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


                    bl.getFilter().filter(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (s.length()==0)
                {
                    refreshFragment();
                }

            }
        });
```

}

This is my adapter code.

```
public class BillsCustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private String[] doc_no;
    private String[]date;
    private String[] cust_name;
    private String[] cust_number;
    private String[] item_count;
    private String[]total_wt;
    private String[]total;
    private String[]balance;
    private String[]bill_type;

    private Activity context;

    public BillsCustomList(Activity context, String[] doc_no, String[] date, String[] cust_name,String[] cust_number,String[] item_count,String[] total_wt,String[] total,String[] balance,String[] bill_type)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.bills_list_view, doc_no);
        this.context =context;
        this.doc_no=doc_no;
        this.date = date;
        this.cust_name = cust_name;
        this.cust_number = cust_number;
        this.item_count= item_count;
        this.total_wt = total_wt;
        this.total = total;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.bill_type = bill_type;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bills_list_view, null, true);
        TextView textViewDocno = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewInvNo);
        TextView textViewDt = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewDt);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView textViewNumber = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
        TextView textViewCount = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCount);
        TextView textViewTotwt = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewTotwt);
        TextView textViewTot = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewTot);
        TextView textViewBal = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewBalanace);
        TextView textViewBt = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewBt);

        textViewDocno.setText(doc_no[position]);
        textViewDt.setText(date[position]);
        textViewName.setText(cust_name[position]);
        textViewNumber.setText(cust_number[position]);
        textViewCount.setText(item_count[position]);
        textViewTotwt.setText(total_wt[position]);
        textViewTot.setText(total[position]);
        textViewBal.setText(balance[position]);
        textViewBt.setText(bill_type[position]);

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve it? Any suggestion or help is appreciated.Thank You.

Comment: Extends BaseAdapter(not ArrayAdapter) and implement your own filter(override getFilter()) and in that filter simply test the query string against the values from whatever columns you want to include in your search.

Comment: this tutorial will help you http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: @Luksprog can you give a code sample I am new to programming.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In ListView class:

```
SearchView mSearch;
mSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.filter(newText);
                return false;
            }

        });
```

In AdapterClass:

```
private List<ModelClass > mArrayList= new ArrayList<ModelClass >();
private ArrayList<ModelClass > arraylist;

    public void filter(String targetText) {

            targetText= targetText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            mArrayList.clear();

            if (targetText.length() == 0) {
                mArrayList.addAll(arraylist);
            } else {
                for (ModelClass mModel: arraylist) {
                        if (mModel.getInvoiceNum()
                    .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).startsWith(targetText)) {
                        mArrayList.add(mModel);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: What is ModelClass here?

Comment: Exactly can you specify what you are trying to do here?

Comment: BillObject is the model class

Answer (score -1):

First, I think you need change your data type, may be you can use an object include them, and override **toString()** method, the method is your filter value, like this:

```
public class BillObject {
    public String doc_no;
    public String date;
    public String cust_name;
    public String cust_number;
    public String item_count;
    public String total_wt;
    public String balance;
    public String bill_type;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // if you want to search by name
        return cust_name;
    }
}
```

Then, in your adapter, use **List<BillObject>** as data source, and do not have to create View each, like this:

```
public class BillsCustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private List<BillObject> dataList;
    private Activity context;

    public BillsCustomList(Activity context, List<BillObject> dataList)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.bills_list_view, doc_no);
        this.context =context;
        this.dataList = dataList;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.bills_list_view, null, true);
        }
        // find view by id
        ...code

        // get data from dataList by position
        BillObject billObject = dataList.get(position);
        textViewDocno.setText(billObject.doc_no);
        textViewDt.setText(billObject.date);
        // like this do more

        return listViewItem;
    }

}
```

Finally, use adapter's filter in **afterTextChanged()**.
If you want to search as your rule, you can loop the dataList, and get data by searchKey